# will be this simple conditional operator optimized at compile time ? (.net)

Tags: c#, .net, performance, optimization, conditional-operator

Working with legacy code, I found I got are lot of statements (more than 500) like this

```
bool isAEqualsB = (a == b) ? true : false;
```

Does it make any sense to rewrite it like this ?

```
bool isAEqualsB = (a == b)
```

Or will be optimized at compile time ?

Thanks in advance,

Santi! =)

Comment: Hint: Use Visual Studio regular expressions to make the find/replace/refactor super quick (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ignore the performance - that's *so* unlikely to be a bottleneck, it shouldn't be what you think about until you've *proved* that it's relevant with appropriate benchmarks.

I would *absolutely* care about the readability though - and from that point of view, I consider the second approach to be much better, and would certainly use it.

EDIT: In terms of optimization, it looks like the C# compiler doesn't optimize it:

```
  // First form
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  ldarg.1
  IL_0002:  beq.s      IL_0007
  IL_0004:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0005:  br.s       IL_0008
  IL_0007:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0008:  stloc.0

  // Second form
  IL_0009:  ldarg.0
  IL_000a:  ldarg.1
  IL_000b:  ceq
  IL_000d:  stloc.1
```

However, it's not the IL that will matter of course - it's what the JIT compiler does. Now even the difference in IL size *may* mean the difference between inlining and not...

Answer (score 4):

It makes sense to replace the first statement regardless of whether it will be optimized or not.

```
bool isAEqualsB = (a == b)
```

This is just cleaner code  `a == b` is a boolean expression, no need for anything else. Think about it as a refactoring to improve maintainability and readability of your code base, not necessarily a performance win.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely rewrite it. The compiler might make this optimization, but that's not important since the code will be much more readable if you put the time in to fix it now.

Better yet, do away with these variable declarations in the first place and replace their uses with `a == b`.

Also, find whoever wrote this code and give them the evil eye :)

Answer (score 1):

If the code is working, I'd leave it the way it is. The time you'll spend rewriting it will never be repaid. Yes, the second approach is cleaner and easier to read, but it's going to take you time to change 500+ occurrences of that pattern, and the chance of making an error--turning working code into non-working code--is non-zero. The small readability benefit you'd get from the refactoring will not make up for the time and the risk involved with making the change.

As far as execution is concerned, the compiler will almost certainly optimize the first into the second. But as others have said, even if the compiler didn't optimize that, the performance gain would be miniscule.

But I would definitely use the second approach for new code.